# webpack-dev-server index.html vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'm getting started with webpack and vue.js. I recently added webpack to a small vuejs website, I was able to get up and running, however I have a small question.

In my root directory I have an `index.html` which is the `index.html` that `webpack-dev-server` uses to render the app. It is to possible to configure `webpack-dev-server` to use the `index.html` that vue.js uses in the `public` folder?

I tried setting the `contentBase` configuration option to point to the public folder, but that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my `webpack.config` file:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                        // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                        // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
                        'scss': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ],
                        'sass': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                        ]
                    }
                    // other vue-loader options go here
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true,
        overlay: true,
        contentBase: "./public/",
        hot: true
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
    // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),

        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })
    ])
}
```

Comment: Can you post you webpack.config here? I would strongly advise that you use [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) it's much easier to get started with Vue

Comment: Hello, I have modified the question to include the webpack.config code. Thanks.

Comment: You might need the HTML webpack plugin. Check this [tutorial](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-vuejs-a-complete-guide-209e943c4772)